# Produce all permutations of a number's digits

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, split, shuffle

I've recently solved a problem, which takes a 3-4 digit number, such as 1234, (as well as some greater numbers) and returns a sorted array of ALL the possible [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the numbers `[1234, 1432, 4213, 2431, 3412, 3214, etc.]`

I don't like my solution, because it used .times to add the numbers to the array, and thus is still fallible, and furthermore ugly. Is there a way that the numbers could be added to the array the perfect number of times, so that as soon as all the possible shufflings of the numbers have been reached, the program will stop and return the array?

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  array = []
  number = number.to_s.split(//)
  1000.times{ array << number.shuffle.join.to_i}
  array.uniq.sort
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as below using [`Array#permutation`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
>> a = 1234.to_s.chars
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
>> a.permutation(4).to_a
=> [["1", "2", "3", "4"],
 ["1", "2", "4", "3"],
 ["1", "3", "2", "4"],
 ["1", "3", "4", "2"],
 ["1", "4", "2", "3"],
 ["1", "4", "3", "2"],
 ["2", "1", "3", "4"],
 ["2", "1", "4", "3"],...]
```

Your modified method will be :

```
def number_shuffle(number,size)
  number.to_s.chars.permutation(size).to_a
end
```

Comment: Ah, the core library delivers. How easy is the answer if you know the correct term. :)

Comment: So true @LeonidShevtsov - knowing the name would certainly have helped.

Comment: @ArupRakshit what do you mean by the permutations part, as in 'a.permutation(4).to_a'? I've run this through the irb and it doesn't understand.

Comment: @modulus `a.permutation(4)` will give you `Enumerator`. Now calling `#to_a`, will convert it to `Array`.

Comment: Why the pointless variable creation? I find `number.to_s.chars.permutation(size).to_a` even easier to read.

Comment: @Max Moved it out.. :) I don't know myself also why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

For your method it will be:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  a = number.to_s.chars
  a.permutation(a.size).to_a.map { |b| b.join.to_i }
end

p number_shuffle 123 # => [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```